# To create a login page should i create a login activity or just an empty activity with textviews and button?

Tags: android

i am trying to create a login page for my app. Should i just take an empty activity and add textviews and buttons or should i start by taking a login activity in android studio? what is the difference between the two and which one should i go for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - of course - use your own layout. No problem with that. 
The Login Activity is predesigned for you, use if if you want. 
It also brings some logic with it which you can use.
Do you have your own authentication process?

You can creat this via the menu
[image]

This is how it looks like.

[image]

and this is the layout tree.

[image]

Do you need some more help?

If you want a real backend server implementation you can read this Article:
 [Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

Comment: Thanks simon, i was a bit overwhelmed by all the methods in the java class. Like we can go for anyone of them right? What do u recommend?

Comment: You can fill the `private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS` for testing.

Comment: I also added a good link to my answer